# Attribute error DESCRIPTOR while trying to convert google vision response to dictionary with python

Tags: python, google-api, google-vision

I am on Windows, using `Python 3.8.6rc1`, `protobuf version 3.13.0` and `google-cloud-vision version 2.0.0`.

My Code is :

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
from google.cloud import vision
    
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
response = client.annotate_image({
            'image': {'source': {'image_uri': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60'}},
        })
MessageToDict(response)
```

It fails at `MessageToDict(response)`, I have an `attribute error: "DESCRIPTOR"`. It seems like the `response` is not a valid protobuf object. Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Any luck? Im hitting the same issue with another google api protobuf object.

Comment: I posted a way to solve this as an answer

Answer (score 30):

This does not really answer my question but I find that one way to solve it and access the protobuf object is to use `response._pb` so the code becomes:

```
response = client.annotate_image({
            'image': {'source': {'image_uri': 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60'}},
        })
MessageToDict(response._pb)
```

Answer (score 7):

Look step 3,

#### Step 1: Import this lib

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict
```

#### Step 2: Send request

```
keyword_ideas = keyword_plan_idea_service.generate_keyword_ideas(
    request=request
)
```

#### Step 3: Convert response to json [Look here, add ".pd"]

```
keyword_ideas_json = MessageToDict(keyword_ideas._pb) // add ._pb at the end of object
```

#### Step 4: Do whatever you want with that `json`

```
print(keyword_ideas_json)
```

*Github for this same issue: [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-datatransfer/issues/63)*

Answer (score 5):

maybe have a look at [this post](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/70)

```
json_string = type(response).to_json(response)
# Alternatively
import proto
json_string = proto.Message.to_json(response)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the github issue @FriedrichSal posted, [you can see](https://github.com/googleapis/python-vision/issues/70#issuecomment-712992731) that `proto` does the job and this is still valid in 2022 (library name is `proto-plus`):

> All message types are now defined using proto-plus, which uses different methods for serialization and deserialization.

```
import proto
objects = client.object_localization(image=image)
json_objs = proto.Message.to_json(objects)
dict_objs = proto.Message.to_dict(objects)
```

The `MessageToJson(objects._pb)` still works, but maybe some prefer not to depend on a "hidden" property.

Comment: This is whats up! Amen brother.