# Put Google Ads API result into Dataframe

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I am using Google Ads API SDK for Python. I want to get some Ads data and put them into a Dataframe to transform a bit. I made a call with the code below:

```
client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage("config.yaml")
customer_id = '<customer_id>'
ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
query = """
    SELECT
        campaign.id,
        campaign.name,
        customer.id
    FROM campaign
    """
response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)
for batch in response:
    for row in batch.results:
        print(row)
        df = pd.DataFrame(row)
        print(df)
```

Here is the response I receive:

```
customer {
  resource_name: "customers/<customer-id>"
  id: <customer-id>
}
campaign {
  resource_name: "customers/<customer-id>/campaigns/<campaign-id>"
  name: "Test_campaign_1"
  id: <campaign-id>
}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(dict(row))
TypeError: 'GoogleAdsRow' object is not iterable
```

I tried using google.protobuf.json_format to convert the result into json/dict format with the below code

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
response = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)
for batch in response:
    for row in batch.results:
        print(row)
        jsonobj = MessageToJson(row)
```

But I got the below error message:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\proto\message.py", line 605, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(str(ex))
AttributeError: 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

Could you please help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for bothering, but I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403737/attribute-error-descriptor-while-trying-to-convert-google-vision-response-to-dic) and got the answer for my question.

I changed my code to below (add ._pb to the response):

```
response = ga_service.search(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)
dictobj = MessageToDict(response._pb)
df = pd.json_normalize(dictobj,record_path=['results'])
print(df)
```

and it works!

Comment: '_StreamingResponseIterator' object has no attribute '_pb'

Comment: Did you find a solution to the above error: _StreamingResponseIterator' object has no attribute '_pb'

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Toàn!

Regarding the questions mentioned in his previous post, I found the following solution to be effective for my situation:

```
search_request.query = query
stream = gads_service.search_stream(search_request)

for batch in stream:
    dictobj = MessageToDict(batch._pb)
    df = pd.json_normalize(dictobj,record_path=['results'])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).